# How do I reset jCarousel after loading AJAX content?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jcarousel

I am using a custom jCarousel JavaScript ( http://pastebin.com/BwsVpNjr ) that I purchased from a template; however, when I try to load content with AJAX the carousel breaks as it cannot deted width or height. How can I make it so that jCarousel reloads after content is inserted via AJAX?

I have spend 4-5 days googling a solution and have seen hundreds of people with similar questions but no definitive answer. Please help me!

Answer (score 0):

After loading the images, you would need to reload the carousel using `.jcarousel('reload' [, options])`

Comment: ok, now where would I place that code? (im a total beginner trying to get my feet wet) in the actual jcarousel js or in the index.php or my content.php?

Answer (score 0):

I managed to fix it like that

```
$("#Services").each(function (index, item) {
        /* Load Content With AJAX */
        var url = site.baseUrl + $(item).data("url");
        if (url && url.length > 0) {
            $(item).load(url,

            /* Check return of load function if success load jcarousel */
            function (responseText, textStatus, XMLHttpRequest) {
                if (textStatus == "success") {
                    if ($('.slidewrap').length && jQuery()) {
                            $('.slidewrap').carousel({
                            speed: 600,
                            slider: '.slider',
                            slide: '.slide',
                            slideHed: '.slidehed',
                            nextSlide: '.next',
                            prevSlide: '.prev',
                            addPagination: false,
                            addNav: false
                            });
                    }
                }
                if (textStatus == "error") {
      // oh noes!
                }
            });
        }
});
```